# Leave approval turnaround time

Tags: leave

My employer has a habit of waiting until the very last moment to approve leave. I want to know if there is a leave approval turn around time or if they have  a right to take their time. It makes it very difficult for me to organise myself when I can't get an answer from them as they are 'too busy.' I have given 6 months notice of annual leave and I know they won't respond until the month of.

Comment: Many employers do this. They are waiting to see what the workload will be like closer to the time period.  It generally helps if I tell them that I need to make airline reservations and need confirmation of the dates. Of course employers can cancel leave requests (at least in the US) after they approve them, so you don't really gain much by having the early approval.

Answer (score 2):

There is no set turn around timeframe that I know of. They can approve it or not whenever they want. But obviously it's not good to leave people hanging like that,